# Nested Loops to Compare Two CSVs in Powershell and Remove Duplicates

Tags: csv, powershell, nested

I'm trying to compare two CSVs then remove entire objects from one if the line name matches the other.  Right now I'm setting it equal to the `$test` variable for validation.  The first line works; I just included it for clarity.

```
#Compare and Output Perfect Matches
    $perfect=compare-object (import-csv $bpa) (import-csv $peak) -Property "Op_Area","Line_Name","From_St","From_Nd","To_St","To_Nd" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent 
#Remove Perfect Matches from Original Two Lists
    $test=import-csv $peak|%{if($_.line_name -eq $perfect|%{$_.line_name}){Remove-Item}}
```

My end goal is to find matches between the two lists (Done in the first line), remove those from both, then switch a few rows around and find a second set of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line_Name` to grab just the `Line_Name` values from the matching entries:

```
# Store the $peak csv in a variable, we'll need it later
$peakData = Import-Csv $peak
$perfect = Compare-Object (Import-Csv $bpa) $peakData -Property "Op_Area","Line_Name","From_St","From_Nd","To_St","To_Nd" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line_Name
```

Then use `Where-Object` to filter out those lines:

```
$test = $peakData |Where-Object { $perfect -notcontains $_.Line_Name }
```